# Determining possible data structures given a set of required operations

Tags: data-structures, sets, dictionaries

This was an interview question that I was told is supposed to be an open ended discussion of the trade-offs. 
You have a collection of comparable objects and want to be able to do the following:
1. Lookup, add, delete objects
2. Get and/or extract Min, max objects
3. Objects should be unique (no duplicates)

A max-heap or min-heap almost fits the criteria except you can only have easy access to either min or max but not both. I ended up saying that if we know if one of max or min is more commonly needed, build a max or min heap.

A hash table is out of the question since the elements are un-ordered although it does have O(1) lookup.

What are the most appropriate data structure(s) in this scenario?

Comment: A balanced binary tree achieves $log(n)$ time for all operations, and tries (e.g. a crit-bit tree) give you constant time for integer or floating-point keys. You could also use a max-heap and a min-heap with a hash-table indexing the positions of each element in the heaps, but this would have large constant factors and substantial implementation complexity.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Since there are no performance criteria given, there are many options.

Comment: BSTs can be augmented to  support selection of any order-statistic in time proportional to the height of the tree without impacting the other operations unduly. That's a popular exercise problem.

Comment: What about min-max heap?

Answer (score 1):

- If there is no restriction on execution time or $n$ stays small then a simple unsorted array is always an option. It gives $O(n)$ execution time for all operations except adding an object and removing by swap-with-back-and-pop. As a less obvious bonus iteration over an array is very cache friendly so it will likely outperform nearly everything for small $n$.
- When you value lookup more than modification you can sort the array, lookups are now $O(\log n)$ and min and max are $O(1)$. But modifications are now $O(n)$ in all cases however they can be amortized a bit by using a small scratch array on the side that gets merged in periodically for additions and tombstone sentinels for removed elements.
- Using a min or max heap will reduce modification time to $O(\log n)$ at the cost of all other operations becoming $O(n)$ except the query for min or max depending on which it is. You can split the data into 2 using a selected pivot element where if smaller then elements get pushed into a min heap and if larger they get pushed into a max heap. Depending on the order of operation you may need to reselect the pivot element is the sizes of the heaps become too unbalanced.

Then there are the node-based solutions:

- Linked list (sorted or not) is not useful at all here, you still have $O(n)$ execution time for nearly everything like with unsorted array with additional cache miss and dependent-load costs during iteration and the only bonus you have is that insert and remove can happen in-place. I'm mentioning it here because:
- You can use a look-ahead list, essentially a sorted linked list with the addition that each node has a finger table of nodes that lets you skip ahead in the list. modifications and lookups are now $O(\log n)$. However it has an element of randomness (how large each finger table is) that can potentially screw you over and regress performance to $O(n)$ for lookups.
- A balanced search tree isn't random in that way and every operation becomes $O(\log n)$ and correct implementation of the balancing routing can be tricky.
- you already mentioned why you don't like the hashtable though the $O(1)$ modification and lookup can outweigh the $O(n)$ cost for min/max. Though keep in mind that there are various ways of implementing one each with various benefits and drawbacks.

Those are the basic data structures I'd select between for holding a set of values. If there are other requirements and performance is a big enough issue then I'll go research more exotic options.